# TSQL - data manipulation - given a time period, break down that time period into smaller periods

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sas

I work in healthcare.  Our data is shit, most of the time.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzRX7.png]

Since I'm not allowed to post pictures yet, above is a link to an image that fundamentally sums up what im trying to do.

For example, I know that recipient 1234 is eligible for reimbursement in the time period jan 2015 - april 2015.

For that example, I would get one row of data:  1234 01/2015 - 04/2015

Since the timespan consists of FOUR months, I need the data to show FOUR ROWS instead of ONE.

I need row one to be:   1234 1
I need row two to be:   1234 2
I need row three to be: 1234 3
I need row four to be:  1234 4

Is there a way to do this in TSQL?  Perhaps some tricky TSQL coding?  Or maybe SAS coding and/or python coding?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details about your table to be any real help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If your data is truly, as you say, shit, then it seems probable that any tricky string manipulation (which is definitely possible with some judicious application of a numbers table and `CROSS APPLY`, but tricky indeed) could easily run afoul of rows that don't match this exalted pattern and break in spectacular ways. Some sort of preprocessing in a proper programming language (or SSIS if you must) is typically far preferable over string manipulation in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS:

```
data want;
   set have(rename=(Month = Month_Range) );

   Date_Start = input(scan(Month_Range, 1,'-','O'), anydtdte.);
   Date_End   = input(scan(Month_Range, 2,'-','O'), anydtdte.);

   do i = 0 to intck('month', Date_Start, Date_End);
       Actual_Date = intnx('month', Date_Start, i, 0, 'B');
       Month       = month(Actual_Date);
       output;
   end;

   format Actual_Date monyy.;

   keep Recipient_ID Month Actual_Date;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, perhaps something like this

```
Declare @YourTable Table (RecipiantID int,Month varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1234,'01/2015-04/2015')


;with cteM(M) As (Select N From (Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) N(N))
     ,cteY(Y) As (Select 1899+Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cteM N1, cteM N2) 
     ,cteD(D) As (Select DateFromParts(Y,M,1) From cteM Cross Join cteY)
Select A.RecipiantID
      ,Month       = Month(B.D)
      ,ActualMonth = Format(D,'MMM-yy')
 From @YourTable A
 Join cteD       B on D between cast(substring(Month,4,4)+'-'+left(Month,2)+'-01' as date) and cast(right(Month,4)+'-'+substring(Month,9,2)+'-01' as date)
```

Returns

```
RecipiantID Month   ActualMonth
1234        1       Jan-15
1234        2       Feb-15
1234        3       Mar-15
1234        4       Apr-15
```